# font size issue of hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, css

```
.link16 a, a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #003366;
}
```

This is the CSS class that i had applied.

```
< asp:HyperLink ID="hlProductDetail" runat="server" CssClass="link16">See full pricing</asp:HyperLink>
```

When i move on to the hyperlink then press the mouse left button and move away from the text. The size of hyperlink changes...

Any one have idea.. why this is happening... and how we can fix it...

Comment: There must be other dependencies you're not including ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Fry_95 ... I solved the problem by

```
.link16 a,
.link16 a:link,
.link16 a:visited,
.link16 a:active,
.link16 a:hover
```

And

```
<div class="link16"> 
   <asp:HyperLink ID="hlProductDetail" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" >See full pricing< /asp:HyperLink >                   
</div>
```

Comment: If it helped you solve your problem, you should mark [Fry_95's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12580647/990877) as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace : `.link16 a, a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover`

By :

```
.link16 a,
.link16 a:link,
.link16 a:visited,
.link16 a:active,
.link16 a:hover
```